# Models Association with SaveAll in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I got dynamic tables so I created 2 models that dynamically. Then I created association of hasOne between them. It works well reading the Data, but I get this error when I use saveAll() **Undefined index: NodeData [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1702]**

I got the code for Node and NodeData models

```
class Node extends PostgresAppModel {
  var $name = 'Node';
  var $useDbConfig = 'pgdata';
  var $useTable = false;
  var $recursive = 0;
```

--

```
class NodeData extends PostgresAppModel {
  var $name = 'NodeData';
  var $useDbConfig = 'pgdata';
  var $useTable = false;
  var $primaryKey = 'node_id';
  var $recursive = 0;
```

In the controller I configured the action:

```
function edit($network_id = null, $variation_id = null, $node_id = null)

    $prefix = $this->Network->getNetworkPrefix($network_id);

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Node->setSource(sprintf('%s_node', $prefix));
        $this->NodeData->setSource(sprintf('%s_node_data', $prefix));
        $this->Node->bindModel(array(
            'hasOne' => array(
                'NodeData' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => 'node_id',
                    'className' => 'NodeData',
                )
            )
        ));
        $this->data['NodeData']['id'] = $this->data['NodeData']['node_id'];
        if ($this->Node->saveAll($this->data)) {
```

I debug the line in model.php, but can't get why $this->{$type}[$association] gives the error

```
$values[$this->{$type}[$association]['foreignKey']] = $this->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The models need to be bound in the models themselves, not in the controller.